# Adding a click handler using queryselector not working

Tags: javascript

I'm sure I am missing something really easy here but I am just trying to add a click event to one of my elements but the console keeps stating 'Null is not an object'

Here is my markup

```
<section class="section active">
  <div class="hidden-content">

  </div>
  <button class="button"></button>
</section>

<section class="section">
  <div class="hidden-content">

  </div>
  <button class="button"></button>
</section>

<section class="section">
  <div class="hidden-content">

  </div>
  <button class="button"></button>
</section>
```

The javascript I am using

```
document.querySelector('.section.active .button').addEventListener('click', function(){
     document.querySelector('.section.active .hidden-content').classList.add('show')
});
```

I know I could do a queryselectorAll like this and add the click handler

```
var hiddenContent = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
         document.querySelector('.section.active .hidden-content').classList.add('show')
    });
}
```

The reason I'm asking is I know that there would only ever be 
 one (section.active .button) at any one time which is why i was surprised queryselector wouldn't work for me as it would only return the first one it found which would be this. (Unless I am wrong of course)

Appreciate any advice to where I have gone wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding the click handler to the `div`, which is hidden, so it never receives and clicks (it has zero size). Putting anything at all in your div makes it clickable.

https://jsfiddle.net/8v0w0nrf/

If you want the action to happen on the buttons instead, select for them.

Using the ".hidden-content" div, like before:

```
var div = document.querySelector('.section.active .hidden-content');
div.parentElement.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', function(){
    //Do something
});
```

Or, you can just go straight to the button:

```
document.querySelector('.section.active .button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Be careful though, you're going to need to update this event listener any time the `section.active` class changes.

Comment: Many thanks Aaron for this. I just realised an error in my markup though. It's actually the button that will have the click handler and not the hidden-content. My fault there